# How to change language in WebSphere MQ Explorer?

Tags: ibm-mq

IBM's advice doesn't work for me: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21454454

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Open file ...\MQExplorer\eclipse\configuration\config.ini and add this lines:

```
org.osgi.framework.language=en
osgi.nl=en_US
```

credits go to: http://blog.ondruska.com/2012/12/switch-eclipse-language.html

Answer (score 4):

With MQ Explorer 9.1.4.0 and following this [reply](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/answers/436809/view.html), you need to change the file at:

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ Explorer\MQExplorer.ini
```

And add the fourth line:

```
-vm
jre/jre/bin
-vmargs
-Duser.language=en
-Xmx512M
```

Comment: 9.1.14 is not a valid MQ version.  Do you mean 9.1.0.4, or do you mean 9.1.4?

Comment: Sorry @JoshMc, yes it is: 9.1.4.0.

Comment: It also works for Version: 9.3.0.0